# I want to remove "only can send one post on half past a hour" limit

Tags: support, feature-request

I want to remove "only can send one post on half past a hour" limit.

Because I want to answer a lot of questions, this restriction has seriously limited the opportunity to help others solve the problem. I personally want to remove this limit

Comment: Then earn more reputation, then the rate limit is lower; once you get to 125 reputation you can answer every 60 seconds without triggering CAPTCHA. See [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

Comment: As a separate note, only *one* of your answers has a positive score and your total undeleted answer score is -1 (at time of writing); that does not demonstrate a good track record. Your most recent answers are "code-only" answers, which could be improved with explanations; as a user who frequently ends up with results from [so] when trying out an unfamiliar technology I often find code-only answers to be less than helpful.

Comment: [This answer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76128699) is not only code-only but deliberately made harder to understand. Either that or you copied some minified code which is basically the same result. The comments just highlight that it's hard to understand: `const req = bT(o, h); // call buildTree function` *you shouldn't need to comment what this line does*. Yet the comment is therebecause `bT` is not named `buildTree` thus hard to follow.

Comment: Can you come up with a more globally acceptable reason to lift this limitation other than because you in particular want to answer a lot of questions? At the moment, it looks extremely self-centered.

Comment: "This restriction has seriously limited the opportunity to help others solve the problem." Maybe, but it also limits the opportunity to add unhelpful/low-quality answers. The question on the main page then shows up as having an answer. If the answer is unhelpful, then arguably this may *hinder* others from solving the problem.

Comment: Due to the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/2029983) on your answers, I suspect you are now in a position where you are answer banned. That is going to be a difficult hole to dig yourself out of. Editing your answers to improve them is going to likely be the best thing to do right now to try and stem the flow of votes, and maybe have some upvotes cast on them if you improve them suitably.

Comment: SNQUphp - please make sure to read tag's info before using them - this often will help you to target posts better. I.e. for ["feature-request"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info): "why the new feature is needed and/or how it can improve the community" - this post definitely lack in "improve the community" part.

Comment: *That is going to be a difficult hole to dig yourself out of.* Nearly impossible, unfortunately. The server takes all answers, deleted and not deleted, into account forever as far we-the-users can tell. And unlike with questions, there's no do-over question every few months you can use to prove that you've improved your habits. Your only chance is to edit and greatly improve pretty much all of your answers and hope future readers will find them helpful enough to upvote.

Comment: Fortunately it costs reputation to downvote, so there's some incentive for downvoters to revisit the answers after they have been revised and remove the downvote or even upvote if the answer has been edited into being a positive contribution.

Comment: If you are submitting more than one answer an hour there is  high chance you are answering questions that shouldn’t be answered or the quality of your answers are low. Every single one of the questions you answered has been poorly received, some to the point, where their authors are likely now questioning banned. Stop answering unclear, poorly received questions, and your experience will improve.

Comment: "I want to answer a lot of questions, this restriction has seriously limited the opportunity to help others solve the problem" Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and make sure you understand why "answering a lot of questions" **does not mean that** you are "helping others solve the problem". Above all, make sure you understand that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: @user4581301 While you're correct (as far as we can tell), it is _much, much_ easier to get out of an answer ban if you have salvageable non-deleted answers.  Improving them and earning some upvotes would go a long way toward getting out of it.

Comment: [Indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76129232/how-to-make-a-button-be-active-one-at-a-time/76129311#76129311). That is a pretty basic requirement.

Comment: *"Because I want to answer a lot of questions"* - enthusiasm is the mother of all question and answer bans.

Answer (score 28):

The rate limit exists to stop users who are yet to demonstrate their familiarity with the site (though I personally think reputation isn't a good indicator either, but that's a different problem) from providing too much content on the site while they *learn* about the site. Many users who have yet to contribute to the site don't actually understand it.

As a result users that have <125 reputation must wait <strike>3 minutes</strike>* 30 minutes between making answer posts; this is detailed in  [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide). Once you get to 125 reputation then you can post answers much more frequently, and trigger a CAPTCHA if you try to post an answer more than once every 60 seconds (at 10k reputation that changes to 30 seconds).

Honestly though, I would even suggest that as a 10k user a limit is "fine". If a user is posting answers *that* quickly (even every 3 minutes) I would be concerned for the quality of their posts; I find that even for the most simple questions it'll take several minutes for me to read the question, understand the requirement, write a solution, *test* the solution, and then write an answer with an explanation alongside the solution (not to mention if it's a simple question, there's probably a duplicate I can close it as, which I frequently do).

As a new user, I don't doubt that the quality of your answer will be affected by the urgency with which you want to create them. Since my [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424419/i-want-to-remove-only-can-send-one-post-on-half-past-a-hour-limit#comment955697_424419) about the content of your answers (code-only) and score (total of -1) your total score is now -9. This will be, in part, due to the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/2029983), but also demonstrates that the quality of your answers isn't good. One user has [expressly informed you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76129533/2029983) that your answer doesn't do what they want/need and though I'm an SME in SQL Server (not MySQL), the technologies are similar enough I can understand both the question and your answer to know that they are worlds apart. This clearly demonstrates that you didn't take the time to understand the question or test the solution you offered.

---

Instead, you need to take a step back; stop trying to provide lots of "ok" or even *bad* content. Instead contribute good answers, which you might do once every few hours or even once a day (as an 86k user I have only contributed about 25 answers in the last 30 days yet have earned about 640 reputation this month; though some will be from older answer volume <> more reputation). Excellent, well-written answers are *far* more likely to be well received, especially when the question is well written too. Then, once you reach 125 reputation, you'll be able to answer a little more frequently. For now, I suggest you be more "choosey" on the questions you answer, and take the time to write them well, by doing your own testing and providing explanations.

<sub>* Previously Stack Overflow used to allow <125 reputation users to post answers every 3 minutes, however, due to (new) users (ab)using  ChatGPT and other OpenAI products to provide huge volumes of uncited, plagiarised, and generally*bad/wrong* AI-generated content, the rate limit was increased to 30 minutes to help stem the flow of content. It's because of those users you can't have nice things.</sub>

Comment: +100 to " I would even suggest that as a 10k user a limit is fine" part: it takes 5+ minutes to check for duplicates alone... and than you need to write, proofread, confirm that code in the answer actually runs/fixes the issue and add necessary links to official/canonical documentation (i.e. W3C/ECMA or MDN for HTML/JS). 30 minutes per question is really fine, it was true all the time, and even more now days with smooth BS generator (aka ChatGPT) produced answers...

Comment: I would, in a heartbeat, trade a 30 minutes per question limit on all users, for a removal of caps on daily close votes.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to post that many answers in such a short amount of time, that indicates that you may not be putting a lot of thought into them. I would encourage you to dedicate more time to each individual answer; make sure you understand the question thoroughly, test your solutions, and provide clear explanations. One well-thought-out answer is much more helpful to future readers than several answers that you haven't thought through thoroughly.

One more suggestion: I would encourage you to save yourself some frustration and only answer well-asked questions. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76128615/how-can-i-establish-a-tree-structure-from-the-given-data) shows very little effort on the OP's part and really doesn't merit an answer. The only possible answer to the question is to do the whole thing for the OP, which is exactly what your answer does. (Also, the answer there could be greatly improved by adding more explanation).